# Assign a R variable a default value unless it has already been assigned?

Tags: r

Is there a idiomatic way of assigning a default value to a variable? But not overwritting it it has been already been assigned?

Currently I settled for

```
myvar <- ifelse(exists("myvar"), myvar, "my default value")
```

but `myvar` is repeated 3 times there. I was hoping to find a construct where I don't need to repeat the variable name something like

```
setdefault(myvar, "my default value") # won't work
```

I know how to assign default values to function arguments (which is very concise) but I wonder if there is something similar for "regular" variables.

Comment: Use a function? Global variables should be avoided.

Comment: Check if it exists (in whichever environment) and use `<<-` as necessary? But as pointed out by @Roland under your answer, this isn't something you should strive for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find any "builtin" that provides and the closest I got to the syntax I want is this:

```
setdefault   <-  function(name, value) {
  if ( ! exists(name) ) {
    cat("assign",name, "the value", value)
    assign(name, value, pos=1) # in the parent environment
  } else {
    cat(name, "is already assigned. Skip\n")
  }
}

setdefault("a", 20)
cat(a,"\n") # 20
setdefault("a", 30)
cat(a,"\n") # 20
```

The function `setdefault()`  defined here will check if the name `exists()` and if not it will `assign(name, value, pos=1)` which is equivalent to `myvar <- value` in the caller's environment.

`options()` can be used as an alternative to globals, those already provide a default mechanism:

```
getOption("a", 20) # 20
options(a=30)
getOption("a", 2) # 30
```

Comment: This isn't something you should be doing in R. R tries to be a functional language. Global defaults are not needed in a functional language.